# returning confirmation from paypal api sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We are creating a paypal express checkout for a business using sinatra. I need to be able to get something returned form the API giving me confirmation that an order payment has gone through. Using this I want to pass a "PAID' value into a database that will match up with the customer. This is the code to set up my paypal express checkout (inside of shopping_cart.erb):

```
<script>
  paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
    // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
    // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
    client: {
      sandbox: '',
      production: ''
    },
    // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
    commit: true,
    // payment() is called when the button is clicked
    payment: function(data, actions) {
      // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
      return actions.payment.create({
        //    curl -v -X POST "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment" \
        //     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
        //     -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
        //     -d '{"intent": "sale", "payer": {"payment_method": "paypal"} },
        transactions: [
          {amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }}
        ],
        redirect_urls: {
          "return_url": "http://www.paypal.com/return",
          "cancel_url": "http://www.paypal.com/cancel"
        }
      });
    },

    // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
      // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
      return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
        window.alert('Payment Complete!');
        window.location.href = "../receipt";
        document.getElementbyId("paypal-button-container").innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' name='clicked' value='paid'>"
      });
    }
  }, '#paypal-button-container');

  function endClicked(){
    document.getElementbyId("paypal-button-container").innerHTML = "<input type='hidden' name='clicked' value='paid'>"
  }
</script>
```

How do I got about getting a confirmation back and then pass something to the db? Here is the portion of my `app.rb that is dealing with it:

```
 post '/receipt' do
  @title = 'Receipt'
  campaign_name = params[:campaign_name]
  user = session[:user]
  cart = session[:cart]
  puts "this is the receipt"
  db.exec("UPDATE orders SET payment_status = 'paid' WHERE campaign_name = '#{campaign_name}' AND customer_name = '#{user}'")
  erb :receipt, :locals => {
    :cart => session[:cart],
    :campaign_name => session[:campaign_name],
    :user => session[:user],
    :message =>"Thanks for your order, here is a receipt you can print for your records."
  }
end


get '/receipt' do
  @title = 'Receipt'
  campaign_name = params[:campaign_name]
  user = session[:user]
  cart = session[:cart]
  clicked = params[:clicked]
  puts "this is clicked '#{clicked}'"
  # if clicked != ""
  #   redirect '/receipt'
  # end

  erb :receipt,:locals => {
    :cart => session[:cart],
    :campaign_name => session[:campaign_name],
    :clicked => clicked,
    :user => session[:user],
    :message =>"Thanks for your order, here is a receipt you can print for your records."
  }
end
```

Comment: Not sure it is wise sharing your client IDs to the world?

Comment: They are sandbox IDs

Comment: But good call :)

Answer (score 0):

after calling the capture API, you should receive a response that includes the payment status. It will tell you whether your payment is complete or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).